# Finding the density function of a disk

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question asks:

> A disk of radius $5$ cm has density $20$ g/cm$^2$ at its center, density $0$ at its edge. Assume its density is a linear function of the distance from the center.
>
> (a) Write an equation for the density in terms of $r$.

- I do not understand how to find the equation for the density in terms of $r$, if someone can help me with this step it will help me proceed with the integral.

> (b) Set up the integral to find the total mass of the disk.

- I know what the limits on both integrals need to be but I just can't figure out how to get the density function.

Thanks.

Comment: Density is a linear equation in terms of r, as given by the question. Don't over think it, it's not hard to get.

Comment: I edited your question to (hopefully) improve readability. If you do not like some (or all) changes, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only need help with a)?

In that case, you know two points of your density function $\rho(r),$ namely $$\rho(0)=20 \quad\text{and}\quad\rho(5)=0.$$ You then have two equations with two unknowns, namely the constants in $\rho(r)=Ar+B$.

Can you proceed from here?